# SERP update frequency

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, change-frequency

Recently I changed my site improving the `title` and `description` metatags of many pages. Looking at Webmaster Tools I saw that Googlebot already crawled the new contents (and also found duplicate titles I promptly fixed), but the search results pages still have the old descriptions and titles.

Is it know how much time is needed by Google to update the SERPs? In your experience, is it something happening really fast or really slow, supposing a rule to exist?

Answer (score 3):

It varies from site to site. This site is very fast. This page is probably in Google's index already. Your site may take days or weeks for new pages t be ffound or existing pages to be updated. It is based on lots of factors but the longer you've been around and the more popular you're content has been with users (I.e. you have attracted lots of links) the more often you'll be crawled and updated.