# How long usually it takes to effect google ranking after revise contents?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, google-ranking, google-index

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SERP update frequency](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25663/serp-update-frequency)

I sightly changed the title, h1 and some keywords in the content on some pages of my site. How long generally it takes to effect the google ranking?  The dates those page were indexed are still a few weeks ago as far as I can see by the cache. The ranking can change only after google index them again?

Answer (score 0):

Google will index your page (the time taken for this operation may vary, usually it does so in 2 weeks - but I had sites that took longer), and then the rankings might start to move (depending on the changes you have made). But yes, G needs to index your content first.

You might speed up the indexing process setting higher frequency on Sitemaps (although it's just an indication to Google, not an instruction) or "Fetch as Googlebot" button on webmasters tools.